# Can't add a new field to an attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, csv, fields-attributes, table

I haven't been able to find a question that matches my situation. I have a .csv file that I made, and I loaded it into arc to join it to another layer. Due to another issue for another question, I have to add a field. Problem is the add field button is greyed out, and I'm not in an edit session.

I can't just add a new field into the .csv, there's another issue blocking me from doing that. Is there a reason why I can't add a new field?

I'm pretty new to using arc, and I haven't been able to find any answer to this online.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just change the content of a csv. However, you can try the followings:

1. In the Table of Content of Arc, right click on the csv -> Data -> Export, you should be able to get a file geodatabase table, you can add field there. So now you can join the layer to it and then add field.
2. Instead of joining the layer to the csv, try joining the csv to the layer. Then add field to the layer